# Sorting row values in orbjs pivot table

Tags: javascript, arrays, git, sorting, reactjs

Below code is from my project file:

```
{
 name: '3',
 caption: 'Career Level',
 aggregateFunc: 'sumText',
 sort: {
     order: 'desc'
     }
}
```

Instead of 'desc' sort I would like a custom sort based on predetermined array.

As per the code from Orbjs on [Github](https://github.com/nnajm/orb/commit/946fd84aabf0d457a07d8fa0a3c1a646508d3742) this is how customfunc can be added:

```
name: '4',
caption: 'Category',
sort: {
       customfunc: function(a, b) {
       if(a.trim() == 'Touch Screen Phones'){
            return -1;
                    }
               if(a < b) return -1;
               if(a > b) return 1;
               return 0;
                   }
             }
         }
```

I would like to have customfunc to sort Career Levels column from my project it contains values like ["P1", "EX", "M4"] (length of array varies).

If I have to sort all elements as per below array. How do I create a customfunc as in this Github issue [link](https://github.com/nnajm/orb/commit/946fd84aabf0d457a07d8fa0a3c1a646508d3742?diff=unified)

```
 ["EX", "M4", "M3", "M2", "M1", "P6", "P5"]
```

Kindly observe: The length of two arrays is not same. I cannot pass array as an argument.

Can you please guide me how to do this?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I loaded data in the order I wanted and it solved the sorting issue for me.

For anyone else using orbjs library - if you are interested to develop it further please do let me know - I will try to be as much help as possible.